# C: Why can't I malloc inside the function

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, malloc, subscript-operator

I have `int *b` and a function

```
void to_Binary(int num, int range, int **bi_res)
{
   int k = num, c = 0, r;
   *bi_res = (int *) calloc(range,sizeof(int));

   while (range >= c) {
        r = k%2; 
        c++; 
        (*bi_res)[range-c] = r; 
        k /= 2;
    }

   return;
}
```

This is an example of how I send `b` to the function

```
 void main
{
   // A small example if you want to replicate. 
   int *b;
   int i = 0;
   to_Binary(56,6,&b);
   while (i < 6) {printf("%d\n",b[i]); i++;}
   return;
}
```

but it gives me seg fault in the loop

**Note:** The function itself works fine and does what it has to do if I access it in other ways but in the case I am required I have to return an array of ints that I can't know the size of

Comment: Because of operator precedence, your code is equivalent to `*(bi_res[range-c]) = r;`. You should get a warning during compilation about this.

Comment: @xing Doesn't work

Comment: @Bobo I know that I need to pass b as &b but it doesn't work

Comment: Is there a reason why you use a `while` loop instead of `for` loop?

Comment: @Barmar No matter how I wrote bi_res it doesn't work, it is as if it didn't allocate memory. In what I posted above is the last instance I tried. I tried for example what xing suggested but it doesn't work

Comment: You have other problems, as shown in the answer.

Comment: How is this even compiling with the `=/` syntax error?

Comment: @Barmar my bad, it is /= in my program not =/. Sorry

Comment: Use copy/paste instead of retyping so you don't make mistakes like that.

Comment: The loop condition would be easier to understand if you wrote `for (index = range-1; index >= 0; index--)` and then used `[index]`.

Comment: As Barmar just said. Use copy paste, because there's no way your main function would compile

Comment: Does `malloc` receive an address of a pointer? No. Does `calloc` receive an address of a pointer? No. Why does your function receive an address of a pointer? If you need to return a pointer from a function, just return a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two problems with the while loop. The first one is that you are using an incorrect expression in this statement

```
*bi_res[range-c] = r;
```

You have to write

```
( *bi_res )[range-c] = r;
```

The second one is that if you will even use the correct expression nevertheless when range is equal to c you will try to access beyond the allocated array due to this increment within the loop

```
c++;
```

Thus the expression

```
range-c
```

will have a negative value.

You could write the loop like

```
while (range != c) {
    //...
}
```

And this statement

```
k =/ 2;
```

contains a syntax error. You mean

```
k /= 2;
```

Pay attention to that the return statement is redundant.

And the function main should be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

and you should free the allocated memory in main.

Comment: Explain how to fix the use of `c`. I think they just need to change `>=` to `>`, right?

Comment: As I told @Barmar I tried to use (*bi_res)[range-c] but it doesn't work and yeah my bad I didn't copy paste and did in my program /= not  =/  the function works as it should if I send an array that is ready but as I wrote below I need to allocate memory to the array inside the function

Comment: did you fix the loop condition?

Comment: `=/` was a copying error, not in the actual code, you can remove it from the answer.

Comment: Your memory allocation is fine, the problems are with other parts of the function.